# How to produce barplot in bins?

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart, histogram

I produce a barplot like this:

```
sns.barplot(data=number_counts, x="number", y="counts")
```

number_counts is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
number counts
1 7
2 8
3 10
4 12
5 14
6 9
7 6 
8 3
9 2
10 1
...etc
```

However, I'd like that the x-axis is in bins. So instead of showing 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...
It shows the bars for 0-5, 5-10, 10-15, etc

I tried using a histogram without success:

```
sns.histplot(data=number_counts, x="number", bins=list(np.arange(0, 100, 5)), stat='count')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want to use `weights` in `histplot` with your precomputed counts. Would be easier to demonstrate with a copy-pasteable example...

Answer (score 0):

I would compute the bins with [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html), then aggregate the counts with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and [`plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
bins = pd.cut(df['number'], bins=np.arange(0, df['number'].max()+1, 5))

df.groupby(bins)['counts'].sum().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Other option:

```
sns.barplot(df.assign(bin=pd.cut(df['number'],
                                 bins=np.arange(0, df['number'].max()+1, 5))),
            x='bin', y='counts'
           )
```